# Comparing two arraylists of unequal size and throwing out the ones that don't have a match

Tags: java

I want to throw out the FormBean object that dosen't have a match in persons arrayList.
Sorry if code is not formatted properly.

I have an arraylist like this

```
ArrayList persons = new ArrayList(); 
persons.add("Bill"); 
persons.add("Chuck"); 
persons.add("Marry");
```

Then I have another arraylist (of UNequal size) like this

```
ArrayList objects = new ArrayList()
for (i++; i < 5; i++) {
    objects.add(FormBean);
}
```

The FormBean class looks like this:

```
class FormBean {
    String person;
    int SSN
    String phoneNumber
}
```

Is there a way to compare the persons arraylist with the person from the FormBean object AND throw out the FormBean object that dosen't have a match in Persons arrayList.

Comment: Yes, there is. Write some code. Also, don't use raw collections; use generics.

Comment: [Hint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Ah, thanks? I can't figure out the code, that's why I'm asking. Thought this was the place to do that.

Comment: You'll typically get better performance if you make `persons` a `HashSet<String>` instead of an `ArrayList`.

Comment: I strongly agree with @MarkPeters, you can face some pretty ugly run-times with cross-referencing array-lists. Not to mention deleting elements from them.

Answer (score 1):

1. iterate through the `FormBean` list
2. if the persons list *contains* the person name from the actual FormBean then
3. store this FormBean in a separate list, that contains all FormBeans that shall be deleted.
4. Finally, iterate through this to-be-deleted list and *remove* the FormBeans in this list from the original FormBeans collection

*Alternative*

Copy all FormBeans, that match your criteria (personslist *contains* person) to a new collection, then drop the old collection and use the new one.

Comment: Make sure to override the `equals` method too.

Comment: And hashcode, if you provide a custom implementation of equals.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29

Make sure `FormBean` implements `.equals(Object o)` so that it returns `FormBean.person.equals(o)` where `o` is the String of the persons name.

```
class FormBean {
    String person;
    int SSN;
    String phoneNumber;

    public boolean Equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof String) {
            return this.person.equals(o); // Case sensitive
        } else if (o instanceof FormBean) {
            return this.equals(((FormBeans)o).person);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: So a `FormBean` is equal to another `FormBean` if they have the same name? What about the SSN and phoneNumber?

Comment: No, please don't do that! Don't abuse `equals` for that. You'll be in deep trouble if you now use `FormBean` instances hashmaps/-sets or anything else that relies on the equals/hashcode contract.

Answer (score 0):

Your remove loop should look like:

```
for (Iterator<FormBean> iterator = objects.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    FormBean bean = iterator.next();
    if (!persons.contains(bean.getPerson())) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Make sure you have `equals` implemented in your FormBean.

Answer (score -1):

First off. WTF is this?

```
ArrayList objects = new ArrayList()
for (i++; i < 5; i++) {
    objects.add(FormBean);
}
```

What is i?

Just loop through the objects list, check for each one to see if there's a match in the other list (see List.contains()) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object) and remove the ones that don't match.